# Remove uneven blank spaces from a txt file in pig

Tags: csv, text, apache-pig

I have a text file with uneven blank spaces and I want to store it as a csv file using pig.My file is of the format

```
2013 210      0  2878 -7543 4  29  20 116
2013 210     10  2875 -7538 4  32  20 116
2013 210     20  2872 -7533 4  29  20 116
2013 210     30  2870 -7527 4  29  20 115
2013 210     40  2867 -7522 4  30  20 115
2013 210     50  2864 -7516 4  29  20 115
2013 210     60  2861 -7511 4  29  20 115
```

Comment: Where is the "uneven blank space"? What is the column delimiter?

Comment: No ides what `pig` is, but in the shell you can compress multiple spaces down to a single one using `tr`'s *"squeeze"* option, i.e. `tr -s ' ' < YourFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having uneven spaces, read the values as a single line first then squeeze the data with a regular expression then use `STRSPLIT` to split the single space separated data.

```
text_data = load 'file.txt' as line;

squeezed_data = foreach text_data generate REPLACE(line, '\\s+', ' ');
```